# Texto em gráfico de barras empilhadas no R

Tags: r, barplot

Quero criar um gráfico de barras empilhadas semelhante ao abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizei o seguinte comando

```
barplot(t(dadosAQI),
        xlab="%",
        col=colAQI,
        horiz = TRUE,
        cex.axis = 0.8,
        cex.names = 0.8,
        las=1
        )
```

Mas não consigo adicionar o texto dentro das barras. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Rodrigo, você pode postar uma parte reprodutível dos seus dados utilizando `dput`? Você provavelmente vai precisar utilizar o comando `text` e selecionar a posição x baseado nos valores dos dados.

Comment: @Moix, tentei salvar o resultado do barplot para usar com o text, não foi eficiente. A saida do dput foi:
structure(list(TMV = c(33.5621055191536, 15.6754220751383, 36.7551724422255, 
16.3251895118863), TCF = c(65.562027434103, 83.015129105287, 
62.0678120510301, 82.3751677678634), TCz = c(0.875867046743407, 
1.30944881957463, 1.1770155067444, 1.29964272025029)), .Names = c("TMV", 
"TCF", "TCz"), row.names = c("430°C - 1°C/min", "430°C - 5°C/min", 
"530°C - 1°C/min", "530°C - 5°C/min"), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso usando `barplot()` e `text()`, você precisa extrair as posições x e y de cada valor que quer plotar.

- Para os valores de y, vamos utilizar o valor retornado pela própria função `barplot`
- Para os valores de x, temos que colocar cada valor no centro de sua barra. Logo, a posição é metade do valor + os valores das barras à esquerda.

Fiz apenas para os dois primeiros grupos, porque obviamente o terceiro não caberia. Mas você pode editar o x manualmente para escolher uma posição que te agrade. Também retirei o argumento `col` já que você não colocou sua definição, mas basta inserir novamente.

Código completo:

```
dadosAQI <- structure(list(TMV = c(33.5621055191536, 15.6754220751383, 36.7551724422255, 16.3251895118863), TCF = c(65.562027434103, 83.015129105287, 62.0678120510301, 82.3751677678634), TCz = c(0.875867046743407, 1.30944881957463, 1.1770155067444, 1.29964272025029)), .Names = c("TMV", "TCF", "TCz"), row.names = c("430°C - 1°C/min", "430°C - 5°C/min", "530°C - 1°C/min", "530°C - 5°C/min"), class = "data.frame") 

par(mar=c(5,7,2,2))
bp <- barplot(t(dadosAQI), xlab="%", horiz = TRUE,
        cex.axis = 0.8, cex.names = 0.8, las=1) 

xpos <- c(dadosAQI[,1]/2, dadosAQI[,1] + dadosAQI[,2]/2)

text(x = xpos, y = bp, label = round(unlist(dadosAQI[,1:2]), 2)) #Temos que arredondar para não plotar várias casas decimais.
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar fazer isso usando o `ggplot2`. Fiz um exemplo que você pode tentar adaptar para os seus dados:

**1.** Criando o banco de dados:

```
dados <- data.frame(
  nomes = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  tipo = c("C","D","C","D"),
  valor = c(10,5,10,5),
  posicao = c(12,7,12,7)
)
```

**2.** Gráfico:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x = nomes, y = valor, fill = tipo)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = posicao, label = nomes), colour = "white") +
  coord_flip()
```

Note que a coluna posição no banco de dados é a que indica o início do texto. No seu caso, é possível que você precise ajustá-la manualmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]