# Como posicionar texto nas colunas intermediárias?

Tags: r

Olá, gerei um gráfico de colunas que é composto por 15 grupos de 3 colunas (cada grupo de 3 refere-se a um paciente em 3 tempos distintos) e gostaria de identificar cada paciente colocando um texto alinhado a cada coluna do meio (em cada grupo de 3).

Segue o código que usei até aqui:

```
ord_interleave_elements <- order(c(seq_along(chemo_dataset$blast_percent), seq_along(chemo_dataset$d15_absol), seq_along(chemo_dataset$d29_absol)))
barplot(unlist(c(chemo_dataset$blast_percent, chemo_dataset$d15_absol, chemo_dataset$d29_absol))[ord_interleave_elements], beside = TRUE, col = c("black", "grey", "lightgrey"), ylab = "Leukemic cell (%) in bone marrow", xlab = "Case number", family = windowsFont("times"))
```

Como posso posicionar a identificação do paciente por cada grupo de 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para alcançar isso, você precisa apenas saber que pode usar o próprio objeto do `barplot` para as posições de `x` na função `text`. Já dei uma [resposta similar sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87018/texto-em-gr%C3%A1fico-de-barras-empilhadas-no-r/87090#87090).

Como seu código não é reprodutível, criei alguns dados (com menos grupos pra ficar mais claro) para demonstrar um exemplo.

Já que você quer um nome por grupo, temos que criar `labels` vazias para a primeira e terceira barra de cada grupo, e também lembrar de repetir os valores de `y` três vezes, uma por barra do grupo.

Você não falou onde quer o nome, então fiz o mais difícil, que é colocar acima. Se quiser abaixo, basta colocar `y = 0` e `pos = 1`, ou algo do tipo.

```
set.seed(42)
dados <- replicate(5, runif(3))
bp <- barplot(dados, beside = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 1), main = "Grupos")
labs <- unlist(lapply(1:5, function(i) c("", paste("Grupo", i), "")))
text(x = bp, y = rep(apply(dados, 2, max), each = 3), labels = labs, pos = 3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]